# group by - order by not working

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm using MySQL 5.5.4, and trying to make private message (memo) for my website.

I want to make page that shows list of incomming/outgoing messages (like this: http://www.iphonefaq.org/images/archives/Copic.png), so I made a SQL query to get all messages

```
SELECT `note`.*, `sender`.`nickname` as sender_nickname, `receiver`.`nickname` as receiver_nickname
FROM (`note`)
JOIN `user` as sender ON `sender`.`user_id` = `note`.`sender_id`
JOIN `user` as receiver ON `receiver`.`user_id` = `note`.`receiver_id`
WHERE (sender_id = 1 or receiver_id = 1)
GROUP BY (if(sender_id > receiver_id, sender_id, receiver_id)), (if(sender_id <= receiver_id, receiver_id, sender_id))
ORDER BY `note`.`note_id` desc
```

(`1` in `(sender_id = 1 or receiver_id = 1)` is user ID who logged in).

I want to get *LATEST* message of their conversation, so I add this `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY `note`.`note_id` desc
```

but does not work. Is this query wrong?

SQL Structure of table `note` is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `note` (
  `note_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sender_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `receiver_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `note_content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `send_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `is_receive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB EFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

please help! many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

'group by' is grouping data by group by columns and calculate other date and make virtual computed column. not calculated original column is not orderd. not mysql that column even not seem.
and i think you not need group by. why use group by ?